# Which is the correct branch instruction for branch if less than

Tags: assembly, branch, 6502

I wrote an answer yesterday to this:
[What's the coolest hack you've seen or done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192479/whats-the-coolest-hack-youve-seen-or-done)
and I was trying really hard to remember my 6502 assembly, and I couldn't for the life of me remember how to branch if less than...

```
  :1
  lda $C010
  cmp #$80
  bcc :1  ; branch if less than? I forget how to do that.
  lda $C000
  jsr $FDF0   ;output the accumulator value to the screen
```

Anybody know what the instruction is?
BNE and BEQ are equals, BCC was for carry, and a CMP is basically an SBC and that affects the carry, but I'm not sure if it works in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**BCC is branch if less than**; BCS is branch if greater than or equal. There's a nice tutorial [here](http://www.6502.org/tutorials/compare_beyond.html).

However stu's code can be written more concisely without CMP:

```
BIT $C010     ;clear the keyboard strobe
:1
LDA $C000     ;check for a keypress
BPL :1        ;taken if no keypress
JSR $FDFO     ;print the key
```

Comment: You're missing a case in your description.  That is, `BCC` is "branch if strictly less" and `BCS` is "branch if greater than *or equal*".

Comment: @NickWestgate, my answer is deleted. You might want to edit out the reference.

Answer (score 0):

First Google hit: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly#Branch

Comment: cheater. :-) I was looking for some lively 6502 discussion from old schoolers like me with better memories. :-)

Comment: First google hit does not have a straight response to the question

Comment: It is for anybody that wants to know more.  Look ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ if you don't want to think.